# Sentences with "Nicht nur [...], sondern auch [...]"

Tags: grammaticality

Are the following sentences correct? I'm especially curious about the first one.

> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern auch sich ausruhen
>
> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern auch er kann sich ausruhen
>
> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern man kann sich auch ausruhen

Answer (score 2):

> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern <s>auch</s> sich **auch** ausruhen.

This is about the different actions possible at that place, so **auch** must be near the second infinitive.

> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern <s>auch</s> er kann sich **auch** ausruhen.

Same with the complete verb phrase *kann sich ausruhen*, BUT:

> Dort kann nicht nur sie sich ausruhen, sondern **auch** er (kann sich ausruhen).

Both actions are the same, so **auch** describes the *er* instead of the second verb phrase. You could even omit the second verb phrase.

> Dort kann man nicht nur gut essen, sondern man kann sich auch ausruhen.

Correct. Same as above.

---

If you are unsure, *auch* behaves pretty much the same as *nicht*.

Comment: In my opinion, the second sentence sounds wrong in both versions. The "sondern" doesn't really fit maybe, because of the switch from "man" to "er". Could be only my problem, too.

Comment: Well, I think so.